# How to return a component only if the component returns something in a single line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have this code and I would like to be able to write this in a single line of code. Would that be possible?

If the component returns elements, return these elements from the parent component. Otherwise, do not return at all, but continue the script.

```
...
const c = someComponent(var);
if (c) return c;
...
```

**Edit**

The purpose is that I want to make the code look cleaner, so ideally I would want it to look like this, where this function potentially replaces the output of the parent component and stops further execution.

```
...
checkSomeVariables(var1, var2);
...
```

Comment: This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Why do you want to write that on "a single line" (by which I assume you mean a single statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "single line" I'm going to assume you mean a single statement or expression (since you could write the code you have on a single line if you wanted).

You can't if you don't already have an identifier to assign it to (`c`). You don't appear to in your example.

If you **did**, you could do this *(though I don't recommend it)*:

```
if ((c = someComponent(var))) return c;
```

but again, `c` would have to already exist (and be writable).

---

If the issue you have with the code in the question is that you have `c` lying around when you're done (and can't use it again if you want to do this again), you could scope it to an anonymous block:

```
{
    const c = someComponent(var);
    if (c) returnc;
}
```

Then `c` doesn't exist outside that block.

Comment: Thank you very much! I edited my question according to your answer

Comment: @Z0q - Re your edit, I don't think you can do better than you already have, which is perfectly clear and completely standard.

Comment: Alright, that sounds acceptable. If there really is no cleaner solution, I'll use this one